# Subset rows by partially matching two columns for words greater than n characters

Tags: python, regex, r, pandas, stringr

I would be open to doing this in python pandas, but in R I have the following df:

```
    result<-structure(list(traffic_Count_Street = c("San Angelo", "W Commerce St", 
"W Commerce St", "S Gevers St", "Austin Hwy", "W Evergreen St"
), unit_Street = c("San Pedro Ave", "W Commerce", "W Commerce", 
"S New Braunfels", "Austin Highway", "W Cypress")), .Names = c("traffic_Count_Street", 
"unit_Street"), row.names = c(1L, 17L, 18L, 34L, 260L, 273L), class = "data.frame")

1             San Angelo   San Pedro Ave
17         W Commerce St      W Commerce
18         W Commerce St      W Commerce
34           S Gevers St S New Braunfels
260           Austin Hwy  Austin Highway
273       W Evergreen St       W Cypress
```

For each row I want to partially match column 1 to 2 if one of the words, greater than 3 characters, matches another.

I would remove:

```
1             San Angelo   San Pedro Ave
34           S Gevers St   S New Braunfels
273       W Evergreen St   W Cypress
```

and keep:

```
17         W Commerce St      W Commerce
18         W Commerce St      W Commerce
260           Austin Hwy  Austin Highway
```

I tried using `stringR` in the following way but it did not work:

`result$unit_Street[str_detect(result$traffic_Count_Street, "\\w{3}")]`

Comment: Something like this? `keep <- str_detect(result[,2], substr(result[,1], 1, 6)); result[keep,]`
`

Comment: @Sumedh could you explain how that works?

Comment: @Sumedh that is very fragile and will fail if the first through 6th string elements are different.

Comment: @PierreLafortune, yes I am aware of that. It works only for the specific use case posted by OP. That's the reason I posted it as a comment

Comment: @DataTx, as pointed out, it makes an assumption that you are trying to detect if the first 6 characters of column 1 exist in column 2. The result is a boolean vector. Then you just subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a distance filter that has a threshold adjustment. Then you can adjust until you are getting the results you want. A Levenshtein distance of 5 worked well in this case:

```
distanceFilter <- function(df, thresh=5) {
  ind <- apply(df, 1, function(x) adist(x[1], x[2]) < thresh )
  df[ind,]
}

distanceFilter(result, 5)
#     traffic_Count_Street    unit_Street
# 17         W Commerce St     W Commerce
# 18         W Commerce St     W Commerce
# 260           Austin Hwy Austin Highway
```

To learn more, see [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and the [R doc help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/adist.html)

Comment: `adist > thresh` if you want the rows with the number of characters or more matching.

Comment: You are thinking of it in reverse. `adist` measures the distance. If you would like to keep rows that are similar, less than the threshold will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my mistake there! Would you consider doing a `gsub` in order to remove the spaces so they are not counted?

Comment: That would be the user's discretion in my opinion.

Comment: @Badger how would you implement gsub? I'm not completely following

Comment: Do this first. `result[] <- lapply(result, function(x) gsub("\\s", "", x))`

Comment: `adist(gsub(" ","",x[1]), gsub(" ","", x[2]))` This would ensure the gapping character does not confound your rules, under the assumption the gap is not considered a character. Pierre is a far superior regex user to me so he may have a better approach. (As I type it his pops up ;) ) Pierre can you comment on the use of \\s (the space character code) over " ", is there a danger when using " "?